# Angular 8: Dynamic Routing only working when using RouterLink?

Tags: angular, routes

I've encountered a weird thing while working with Angular dynamic routing.
Dynamic routes are only working when called by a `RouterLink`.
But whenever I try to access the route by entering the URL directly into the browser the app crashes.

(Dev console logs `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` for every required script file)

Is there something that I'm missing, or is there a specific reason why the dynamic routes only work when called by a `RouterLink`?

For anyone interested, here are some pieces of code:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: "user", component: UserComponent },
   { path: "user/:userID", component: UserDetailComponent }
];
```

HTML

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li *ngFor="let user of users">
      <a [routerLink]="['/user', user]">{{ user }}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Really sorry if this is a moronic issue, but I've been struggeling with this for days now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HashLocationStrategy`. By Replacing `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` with `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`.

Refer : https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/ for more details.